# i try to create a react app using the command npm create vite@latest my-react-app --template react, but it has issues

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, vite

```
PS C:\Users\Izora\Documents> npm create vite@latest my-react-app --template react
Need to install the following packages:
create-vite@5.0.0
Ok to proceed? (y) y
√ Select a framework: » React
√ Select a variant: » JavaScript + SWC

Scaffolding project in C:\Users\Izora\Documents\my-react-app...

Done. Now run:
PS C:\Users\Izora\Documents\my-react-app> app: sill idealTree buildDeps
PS C:\Users\Izora\Documents\my-react-app> npm run dev

> my-react-app@0.0.0 dev
> vite

'vite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

it gives me that error and i can't start the app. the package.json is created as well as the other app files like app.jsx
the package.json looks like this

```json
{
  "name": "my-react-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: _`app: sill idealTree buildDeps`_  is that really what you ran? Doesn't look right at all

Comment: You seem to have followed the directions incorrectly. You're meant to run `npm create vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template vue` (note the `--` on its own), then run `cd my-react-app`, then `npm install`, then finally `npm run dev`

Comment: is it the -- --template vue or -- --template react?
cuz i'm for a react app

Comment: Sorry yes, but it's still `npm create vite@latest my-react-app -- --template react` which is not what you have in your question